# async doesn't invoke move constructor in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

I have a problem compiling the code containing the following on Visual Studio 2015 Community

```
auto f = async(launch::async,                  
          &WorkerThread<Hash>::run,                 
          WorkerThread<Hash>(mInputFile, mOutputFile),
          i, numthreads, mBlockSize);                   
futures.push_back(std::move(f));
```

Well, similar questions have been asked here dozens of times, but usually the problem was the absent `std::move` somewhere.

Template class `WorkerThread<Hash>` is not copyable (has deleted copy constructor and copy assignment operator), but is movable. The above code produces `C2280:  "WorkerThread<Hash>::WorkerThread(const WorkerThread<Hash> &)": attempted to reference deleted function` (this is my translation).

It seems like it is not generating move constructor by default, which would be fine in my case. When I explicitly set them to `default`, I get the same error, but now it refers to `std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,_Ty,WorkerThread<Hash>,unsigned int,unsigned int,__int64>::_Binder(const std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,_Ty,WorkerThread<Hash>,unsigned int,unsigned int,__int64> &)`.

Any ideas are very welcome.

**Update: [MCVE](https://ideone.com/try3gl)**

If you have the mentioned compiler available, please, try to compile this and report the result. I think it might me an installation problem.

```
#include<future>
#include<memory>


class Foo {
public:
    Foo() :mData(new int[100]) {}
    void run() {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> mData;
};


int main()
{
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo::run, Foo());
    f.get();
}
```

Comment: you didn't post all of the errors, but my guess is that maybe you should use futures.emplace_back(std::move(f));  instead of push_back?

Comment: @Jonathan, no, the same result

Comment: @T.C., Done. This code doesn't compile for me.

Comment: MSVC bug. It's packaging it into a `std::function`, which it isn't supposed to.

Comment: @SimonKraemer No, I shouldn't. See MCVE link, it works fine with gcc.

Comment: Your examples are wrong: You should pass the caller as a pointer and not as a reference/value

Comment: @vehsakul Compare https://ideone.com/f5OFmL with https://ideone.com/WZFKks

Comment: @SimonKraemer your examples are incorrect.
the deleted copy ctor should be const Foo& and you need to std::move the foo instance into the async call in order for it to compile.
https://ideone.com/RxVHLF

Comment: @SimonKraemer yes, your workaround works but the bug still exists. The reason it works is that async should work _both_ with pointers and references, check [this](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread). Jonathan's comment is also correct.

Comment: @vehsakul I didn't know that this is accepted by `std::thread`, thanks for pointing it out. A workaround might be something like this: `auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, [] {Foo().run(); });`

Comment: There are several bug reports related to this on MS Connect. The latest I could find is: [std::async (still?) does not accept move only types](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1582910/std-async-still-does-not-accept-move-only-types). It wouldn't hurt to upvote it and mark it as reproducible. This is annoying, as their `std::thread` implementation seems to support move-only args just fine (you could use this as a workaround, I guess).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: The bug has been fixed in MSVC 2015 Update 2.

This is a [MSVC bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1582910/std-async-still-does-not-accept-move-only-types) (hat tip @bogdan for finding the report). Its `async` (and `packaged_task`, it seems) implementation stores the functor into a `std::function`, which doesn't support move-only types - and therefore cannot be used in a conforming implementation.

A simple workaround is to use a `shared_ptr` instead:

```
auto f = async(launch::async,                  
          &WorkerThread<Hash>::run,                 
          std::make_shared<WorkerThread<Hash>>(mInputFile, mOutputFile),
          i, numthreads, mBlockSize);                   
futures.push_back(std::move(f));
```

Lambdas (along the lines of `[=]{WorkerThread<Hash>(mInputFile, mOutputFile).run(i, numthreads, mBlockSize); }`) can also be considered, but that results in a change in behavior: the `WorkerThread<Hash>` is no longer constructed in the thread calling `async`, but in the thread `async` spawns.

Comment: See if you can find a video of Herb Sutter presenting on the subject of `std::async`.  IIRC, not a huge fan of it - due to a number of design deficiencies.